# NullPointerException при попытке найти View фрагмента из Активити

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Хотел добавить *content_record.xml* в `ViewPager` для `Tablayout`с помощью `Inflater`. После добавления всё было нормально, но когда начал добавлять код для обработки данных элементов из *content_record.xml*, то не могу понять как нужно искать элементы из *content_record.xml*. Пытался создать статическую переменную `layout` типа данных `View` в классе `MainData` и найти элементы через неё в классе `RecordActivity` таким образом:

`MainData.layout.findViewById()`

в итоге получил:

> NullPointerException

Пытался также создать объект класса `LinearLayout` и найти его по идентификатору `findViewById(R.id.content_record`, а потом найти элемент в этом объекте класса элементы `linearLayout.findViewById()`, получил ту же ошибку. Как мне правильно найти элементы по идентификатору из *content_record.xml*?

Класс **RecordActivity**:

```
public class RecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String date;
    String time;
    int minute;
    int second;
    int hour;
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
    String min;
    String sec;
    String h;
    String d;
    String m;
    String sn;
    String route;
    EditText SNum;
    EditText RNum;
    ViewSwitcher plus;
    ViewSwitcher minus;
    ViewSwitcher snanim;
    ViewSwitcher rnanim;
    TextView tv;
    int count = 0;
    Button fill;
    TextView sernum;
    TextView routenum;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        fill = (Button) MainData.layout.findViewById(R.id.button); //Вот здесь ошибка
        tv = (TextView) MainData.layout.findViewById(R.id.textView2); //Вот здесь ошибка
        plus = (ViewSwitcher) MainData.layout.findViewById(R.id.PlusAnimation); //Вот здесь ошибка
        minus = (ViewSwitcher) MainData.layout.findViewById(R.id.MinusAnimation); //Вот здесь ошибка
        snanim = (ViewSwitcher) MainData.layout.findViewById(R.id.SerialNumberAnimation); //Вот здесь ошибка
        rnanim = (ViewSwitcher) MainData.layout.findViewById(R.id.RouteNumberAnimation); //Вот здесь ошибка
        sernum = (TextView) MainData.layout.findViewById(R.id.SerialNumber); //Вот здесь ошибка
        routenum = (TextView) MainData.layout.findViewById(R.id.RouteNumber); //Вот здесь ошибка
        final Animation rotatePlus = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.plusrotateanimation);
        final Animation rotateMinus = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.minusrotateanimation);
        final Animation fadeinPlus = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.plusfadeinanimation);
        final Animation fadeoutPlus = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.plusfadeoutanimation);
        final Animation fadeinMinus = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.minusfadeinanimation);
        final Animation fadeoutMinus = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.minusfadeoutanimation);
        final Animation flipinanimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipin);
        final Animation flipoutanimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipout);
        final Animation quakeanimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.quake);
        snanim.setInAnimation(flipinanimation);
        snanim.setOutAnimation(flipoutanimation);
        rnanim.setInAnimation(flipinanimation);
        rnanim.setOutAnimation(flipoutanimation);
        plus.setInAnimation(fadeinPlus);
        plus.setOutAnimation(fadeoutPlus);
        minus.setInAnimation(fadeinMinus);
        minus.setOutAnimation(fadeoutMinus);
        SNum = (EditText) MainData.layout.findViewById(R.id.SerialNumberEdit); //Вот здесь ошибка
        RNum = (EditText) MainData.layout.findViewById(R.id.RouteNumberEdit); //Вот здесь ошибка
        final Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        if (minute < 10) {
            min = "0" + minute;
        } else {
            min = String.valueOf(minute);
        }
        second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        if (second < 10) {
            sec = "0" + second;
        } else {
            sec = String.valueOf(second);
        }
        hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        if (hour < 10) {
            h = "0" + hour;
        } else {
            h = String.valueOf(hour);
        }
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (day < 10) {
            d = "0" + day;
        } else {
            d = String.valueOf(day);
        }
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        if (month < 10) {
            m = "0" + month;
        } else {
            m = String.valueOf(month);
        }
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        time = String.valueOf(h) + ":" + String.valueOf(min) + ":" + String.valueOf(sec);
        date = String.valueOf(d) + "." + String.valueOf(m) + "." + String.valueOf(year);
        plus.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    plus.showNext();
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    plus.showNext();
                    count++;
                    tv.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    plus.startAnimation(rotatePlus);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        minus.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    minus.showNext();
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    minus.showNext();
                    if (count > 0) {
                        count--;
                        tv.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                        minus.startAnimation(rotateMinus);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        fill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (SNum.getText().length() < 4) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.enough_characters_serial), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    snanim.startAnimation(quakeanimation);
                    return;
                } else {
                    sn = String.valueOf(SNum.getText());
                    sernum.setText("Серийный номер: " + sn);
                }
                if (RNum.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.enough_characters_route), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    rnanim.startAnimation(quakeanimation);
                    return;
                } else {
                    route = String.valueOf(RNum.getText());
                    routenum.setText("Маршрутный номер: " + route);
                }
                snanim.showNext();
                rnanim.showNext();
                if (fill.getText().equals(getString(R.string.fill_button_text))) {
                    fill.setText(getString(R.string.change_button_text));
                } else {
                    fill.setText(getString(R.string.fill_button_text));
                }
            }
        });
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Главная"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Датчики"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Экстренный вызов"));
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        setupViewPager(pager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    }
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.add(new MainData(), "Главная");
        adapter.add(new MainData(), "Датчики");
        adapter.add(new MainData(), "Экстренный вызов");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("count", count);
        outState.putString("sn", sn);
        outState.putString("rn", route);
    }

    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(SavedInstanceState);
        count = SavedInstanceState.getInt("count");
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        sn = SavedInstanceState.getString("sn");
        sernum.setText("Серийный номер: " + sn);
        route = SavedInstanceState.getString("rn");
        routenum.setText("Маршрутный номер: " + route);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecordActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.end_session);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.session_is_not_ending);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.end_button_text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel_button_text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(MainActivity.properties, true);
            if (MainActivity.i > 0) {
                fw.append("\n").append(sn).append("_").append(route).append("_").append(date).append("_").append(time);
            } else {
                fw.append(sn).append("_").append(route).append("_").append(date).append("_").append(time);
            }
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Класс **MainData**:

```
public class MainData extends Fragment {
static View layout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_record, container, false);
        return layout;
    }
}
```

Класс **ViewPagerAdapter**:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void add(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Код **content_record.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.testprogram.alex.tram.RecordActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_record"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.testprogram.alex.tram.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_record"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

            <ViewSwitcher
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/MinusAnimation"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/MinusIn"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/minus_in_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/minus1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/MinusOut"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/minus_out_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/minus2" />
            </ViewSwitcher>

            <ViewSwitcher
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/PlusAnimation"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/PlusIn"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/plus_in_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/plus1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/PlusOut"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/plus_out_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/plus2" />
            </ViewSwitcher>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/start_value_count"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Начало"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FAIL"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PASS"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:textColor="#001aff"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/SerialNumberAnimation">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/SerialNumberEdit"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/enter_sn"
                android:layout_marginBottom="23dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/SerialNumber" />

        </ViewSwitcher>

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/RouteNumberAnimation">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/RouteNumberEdit"
                android:hint="@string/enter_route"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="28dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/RouteNumber" />
        </ViewSwitcher>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fill_button_text"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/end_button_text"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Код **activity_record.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.testprogram.alex.tram.RecordActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".RecordActivity"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: вы не можете обращаться напрямую из активити к `View` фрагмента. Читайте [этот гайд](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragment-view.php) по взаимодействию активити с `View` из фрагмента.

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо большое! Теперь всё понятно!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Логику работы с разметкой фрагмента надо делать во фрагменте, не в активити. Т.е. ищите и обрабатывайте в `onCreateView` фрагмента.
2. Заносить разметку фрагмента в статическую переменную - предельно плохая идея. Не надо так.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Всё работает!